# Interview Question: Remove repeating numbers at the end of an array

Tags: algorithm

I got a surprising interview question today at a big Bay Area tech company that I was absolutely stumped by despite seeming so easy. Was wondering if anyone has seen it or can offer a simpler solution as the interviewer didn't want to show me the answer. The solution can be written in any language or pseudocode.

Question:

Given a list of numbers, remove any extraneous repeating suffix sequences of numbers that appear at the end of the list until it has no repeating suffix sequences. The repeating sequence can be cut-off.

For example:

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6] -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
explanation: [5, 6, 7] were repeating
```

Also consider the situation

```
[1,2,3,4,5,4,5,1,4,5,4,5,1,4,5,4,5,] -> [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,1] # not [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,1,4,5,4,5,1]
explanation: [4,5,4,5,1] is a repeating sequence
```

Comment: I wonder about the claims of which segment is repeating. I would have said `[7,5,6]` was the repeating segment in the first example and that `[1,4,5,4,5]` was the repeating segment in the second example.

Comment: That's a great observation @Ouroborus, I think as long as you can produce a non-repeating result at the end, it is valid.

Comment: What should we remove exactly? The longest suffix that repeats however many times, the suffix that repeats most times, or the suffix that is the longest including repetitions?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Do you have an example where the three possibilities will lead to a different output? Keep in mind that in the two examples above, even if you identified `[7,5,6]` as repeating instead of `[5,6,7]`, the output should remain the same `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,6] -> [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]`

Comment: I'm not sure how you concluded that `[5,6,7]` is valid here, `[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,6]` does not end in `[5,6,7]` and has no repeated occurrences of `[5,6,7]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are always two ways to approach this topic. Finding any solution and finding an efficient one. It is usually better to start with any and then think on how to optimize it.

Now as we can see in the second example, the problem is complicated by the fact that the repeating pattern is not known. So we could just do it for all the possible patterns at the end. Then we would need to check two things

1. is it actually repeating
2. how long is the result
   Then we could just take the shortest result. Here is the Python code:

```py
def remove_repeating_tail(a: list) -> list:
    results = []
    for i in range(len(a)):
        tail = a[i:]
        results.append(remove_repeats(a, tail))

    if len(results) == 0:
        return a
    return sorted(results, key=len)[0]
```

Also we made sure we cover all the cases. Empty list, no repeating pattern. Next we need to write `remove_repeats`. Also we check the empty repeating pattern, so we need to be aware of that.

```py
def remove_repeats(a: list, tail: list) -> list:
    assert len(tail) <= len(a)
    if len(tail) == 0:
        return a

    remainder = a
    count = 0
    while remainder[-len(tail):] == tail:
        remainder = remainder[:-len(tail)]
        count += 1
    if count <= 1:
        return a
    return remainder
```

We remove the repeating pattern and then add it back at the end. Now it's time to test the code if it actually works, if that is possible in the interview.

```
remove_repeating_tail([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,5,6,7,5,6])
-> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

remove_repeating_tail([1,2,3,4,5,4,5,1,4,5,4,5,1,4,5,4,5])
-> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5]
```

Also good to check some other cases:

```
remove_repeating_tail([1,2,3,4])
-> [1, 2, 3, 4]

remove_repeating_tail([])
-> []
```

After quite a bit of fixing we got the above, which I think is correct. In particular I missed:

- first I had an infinite loop in `remove_repeats` for an empty tail
- `remove_repeats` removed always the tail and sometimes everything, as I wasn't checking that there is at least one repeat. I then added the counting.
- I made simple mistakes like writing `results = res` instead of `results.append(res)` leading to some Exceptions.
- Then a lot of simplification. First I used some sentinel `None` to communicate back that it is not repeating, but we could just return the whole list. Then I checked the repeating with some if before the while loop, but realized its basically doing the same as the first iteration, so I used counting.
- Similarly I don't like the `if len(results) == 0:` check. I would probably add `a` to the result in the beginning and remove the check, as now there is always a result. Then we could start the counting from `1` instead of `0`. Still I kept it in.

If we want something fast, we first need to analyze the complexity.

So remove repeating tails for a list of size `n` and tail size `k` is: `O(n / k)`. Then we call this function n times. And then we sort it. Wait why do we sort it, we could just take the minimum `return min(results, key=len)`. That's better.

In each loop we call `remove_repeats` starting with `k = 1` to `n`. So we have:
`sum(k = 1 .. n) O(n / k)`. This is `n / 1 + n / 2 + n / 3 + .. n / n`. I had to look this up on Wikipedia, but these are called [harmonic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number). We can also just make our live easy and say its less than O(n^2) for now. Otherwise I found an approximation of `H_n = n ln(n) + 0.5 n` [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/462188/what-is-the-sum-of-this-fraction-series). So the complexity overall is `O(n log n)`. Not to bad I would say. Is it the optimal? Maybe. Here I would compare it to some other similar algorithms (like substring search, etc).

Before going there, at this point, I would check with the interviewer, where he would like to go next. As there are many directions.

Comment: I think this could work, although I think you need to recurse until it returns the original input via `return remove_repeating_tail(sorted(results, key=len)[0])` in `remove_repeating_tail` for certain edge cases

Comment: Can you give me such an edge case, so we can test it?

Comment: `[1,2,3,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,2,1,1,2]`

Comment: But isn't the only solution [1 2 3 1 1 2 2 1 1 2]?

Comment: No the incomplete tail and the repeating suffix sequence has to be removed (except just one copy).

Answer (score 1):

This seems a tricky question and there may not be a simple solution. Best solution I can think of would be `O(n)` time and `O(n)` and that is if I am not missing any edge case.

Let's take as example

```
[1,2,3,4,5,4,5,1,4,5,4,5,1,4,5,4,5] -> [1,2,3,4,5,4,5,1]
```

Steps would be as follows:

1. Iterate over the input array from last index to first and build a dictionary (hashtable) with every number in the array being a key and value: a list of positions where the specific number is found in the array.

Occurrences dictionary will become:

```py
{
    5: [14, 11, 9, 6, 4],
    4: [13, 10, 8, 5, 3],
    1: [12, 7, 0],
    3: [2]
    2: [1]
}
```

2. Find the possible suffix lengths by calculating deltas between every position and first position for every number. This way we take into consideration the case in which a specific number repeats in the suffix or in the prefix.

We then add each distinct possible suffix length to a set.

3. We sort the possible suffix lengths in descending order.

We get following suffix lengths:

```
[12, 10, 7, 5, 2]
```

4. For every possible length `l`, we test if `arr[n-1] == arr[n-1-l]`. If `l` is our suffix's length, it means that the number at last position is repeated at exactly `l` positions before. We then check the last `l` elements to respect the same condition. If they do, we found the maximum suffix length. If not, the max suffix length is even smaller, so we check the next possible length.
5. After finding the correct suffix length, we delete the remaining numbers that repeat at positions `pos-l`. We then return the slice of array with suffix removed.

```py
def removeRepeatingSuffixes(arr):
    if not arr:
        return []
    n = len(arr)
    occurrences = {}
    for i in range(n - 1, -1, -1):
        c = arr[i]
        if c not in occurrences:
            occurrences[c] = []
        occurrences[c].append(i)

    # treat edge case: no repeating suffix
    if len(occurrences[arr[n-1]]) == 1:
        return arr

    # create a set of possible suffix lengths, 
    # based on the differences between the positions of each number.
    possible_suffixes_lengths_set = set()
    for c, olist in occurrences.items():
        if len(olist) >= 2:
            for i in range(len(olist)-1):
                delta = olist[i] - olist[len(olist)-1]
                possible_suffixes_lengths_set.add(delta)

    suff_lengths = sorted(possible_suffixes_lengths_set, reverse=True)
    for l in suff_lengths:
        if arr[n - 1] == arr[n - 1 - l]:
            # possible suffix length, check if last l characters repeat
            ok_length = True
            for j in range(n-2, n-1-l, -1):
                if arr[j] != arr[j-l]:
                    ok_length = False
                    break
            if ok_length:
                last_i = n-1-l
                while last_i > 0 and arr[last_i] == arr[last_i - l]:
                    last_i -= 1
                # return non-repeating slice, from 0 to last_i
                return arr[0:last_i + 1]
```

Comment: Interesting solution, would the first parts of generating the possible suffix lengths be considered an optimization? As it seems you could technically start at length = length of the input.

Comment: Also, I do not think this would O(n) time in some edge cases for example when the sequence is comprised entirely of either 1s or 0s.

Answer (score -2):

quick way to remove repeating or dedupe is change to a type set() instead of a list

Comment: The order and sequence of the elements is important, not just the set of elements themselves.